# Добавление записей в бд используя ajax

Tags: ajax, php, база-данных, mysql

Добрый день! Я ajax практически не знаю, просто копался в интернете за этот день. В итоге накатал код который поидее должен был добавлять запись без перезагрузки и тут выводить ее в таблице. Однако, что-то ничего не происходит при нажатии кнопки "добавить". Кто опытным взглядом может определить в чем ошибка?

Вообщем имеется таблица article с полями:

- `article_id integer not null auto_increment primary key;`
- `article_title varchar(300);`

И имеются два файла:

- index.php в котором есть вывод данных из таблицы и скрипт ajax по поводу передачи данных на вставку.
- addArticle.php - файл в котором идет вставка записи;

Код файла **addArticle.php**:

```
    <?php
    $article_title = $_POST['article_title'];

    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "managerarticle");

    if($connect->query("insert into article (article_title) values ('$article_title')"))
      echo "OK";
    else
      echo "ОШИБКА В ЗАПРОСЕ!";
    ?>
```

Код основного файла **index.php**:

```
<?php
  // mysqli(хост, пользователь, пароль_пользователя, название_БД)
  $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "managerarticle");
  $connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Сайтик</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="layout/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"> 
  $(document).ready( function() 
  { 
   // обрабатываем событие нажатия на кнопку "Добавить новый товар"   
   $('input[name=addArticle]').click( 
       function () 
       {
          var article_title = $('input[name=article_title_new]').val();
          // отправляем AJAX запрос
          $.ajax(
             {
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/MyAjax/addArticle.php",
                data: "article_title=" + article_title,
                success: function(response) 
                {
                   if(response == "OK")
                   {
                      alert("Товар " + article_title + " добавлен!");
                      location.reload();
                   }
                   else
                   alert("Ошибка в запросе! Сервер вернул вот что: " + response);
                }
             }
             );
       }
    );
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">Редактор статей по технологии Ajax</div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Главная страница</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="header-pic"> <img src="info/header-pics/index-header.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="content">
      <h1> Редактор товаров</h1>
      <div>
      Добавить товар:<br>
      <input type="text" name="article_title_new"  placeholder="Название товара">
      <input type="button" name="addArticle" value="Добавить новый товар"><br>
      </div><br>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <caption>
        Товары
        </caption>
        <tr>
          <th >Номер товара</th>
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>Редактирование</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
          // достаем из базы данных ID и заголовок всех статей
          $result = $connect->query("select article_id, article_title from article");
          //определяем количество полученных записей
          $colResult = $result->num_rows;

          if($colResult > 0)
          {
            for($i = 0; $i < $colResult; $i++)
            {
               $row = $result->fetch_object();
               echo"<tr>";
               echo "<td>".$row->article_id."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row->article_title."</td>";
               echo "<td><center><input type='checkbox' name='delete_button[]' value='".$row->article_id."'></center></td>";
               echo "</tr>";    
            }
          } 
        ?>
      </table>

    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

И вообщем этот код не срабатывает. Почему не добавляется запись ни в таблицу, ни соответственно не выводится в теге таблицы. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: По коду (хтмл index.php) у Вас не подключена библиотека jquery. Поэтому и не срабатывает скрипт отправки данных.

Comment: нет я подлючил ее). Просто тут пропустил код. Сейчас поправлю) пишу вот так: src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js". Ошибка судя по всему в коде ajax, просто я ее не вижу... Потому прошу помощи.

Comment: alert вылазиет на `success(response){ }`?

Comment: нет никаких окошек нет не появляется. Похоже что success не срабатывает.

Comment: А трейсинг в консоле браузер вы делали? запрос отправляется? Событие на инпут повесилось?

Comment: не знаю что такое трейсинг... как это можно проверить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, вытащи свой JS код из <script> в которой ты подгружаешь `jquery`, создай отдельный `<script>` для кода.
Во вторых, `data:{ article_title:article_title }`
http://pastebin.com/DR9g9rLR
PS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">

   $(document).ready( function() 
   { 
    // обрабатываем событие нажатия на кнопку "Добавить новый товар"   
    $('input[name=addArticle]').click( 
        function () 
        {
           var article_title = $('input[name=article_title_new]').val();
           // отправляем AJAX запрос
           $.ajax(
              {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "http://localhost/MyAjax/addArticle.php",
                 data: "article_title=" + article_title,
                 success: function(response) 
                 {
                    if(response == "OK")
                    {
                       alert("Товар " + article_title + " добавлен!");
                       location.reload();
                    }
                    else
                    alert("Ошибка в запросе! Сервер вернул вот что: " + response);
                 }
              }
              );
        }
     );
   });
  </script>
```

Браузером корректно не обработается, нужно сделать

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready( function() 
   { 
    // обрабатываем событие нажатия на кнопку "Добавить новый товар"   
    $('input[name=addArticle]').click( 
        function () 
        {
           var article_title = $('input[name=article_title_new]').val();
           // отправляем AJAX запрос
           $.ajax(
              {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "http://localhost/MyAjax/addArticle.php",
                 data: "article_title=" + article_title,
                 success: function(response) 
                 {
                    if(response == "OK")
                    {
                       alert("Товар " + article_title + " добавлен!");
                       location.reload();
                    }
                    else
                    alert("Ошибка в запросе! Сервер вернул вот что: " + response);
                 }
              }
              );
        }
     );
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Если не доходит, то прежде чем писать, ознакомтесь с базовыми мануалами, там все подробно описано...
PS: имяпредущейпостпеременной: "данные этой самой перменной"
В вашем случае: data:{ article_title:$('input[name=article_title_new]').val() }

Comment: Я же вроде перед этим написал строку var article_title = $('input[name=article_title_new]').val(); А потом переменную article_title присвоил полю article_title. Или я неправильно сделал? Почему двоеточие стоит вместо равно? Я по примеру в интернете делал, там вроде = использовалось... вот ссылка на статью http://workmake.ru/veb-razrabotka/uchimsya-otpravlyat-ajax-zaprosyi-s-pomoshhyu-jquery-v-mysql-i-generirovat-otvet-na-php-v-formate-json-rabochiy-primer-stranitsyi-upravleniya-statyami/

Comment: Делайте по шагам копипаст нынче не в моде.

Comment: Да я оттуда собственно взял только запрос ajax подправил его под себя, а он не работает. И выяснилось что одни делают присвоение через = , другие через : .Не знаю кто прав... Тороплюсь, потому что завтра надо уже сделать все операции добавления, изменения, удаления без перезагрузки. А времени на изучения Ajax Не хватает.

Comment: Во первых, вытащи свой JS код из <script> в которой ты подгружаешь jquery, создай отдельный <script> для кода.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DR9g9rLR

Comment: Спасибо, avengerweb! Отделение скрипта от подгрузки jquery решило проблему. Все остальное было правильно и в старом варианте.

Answer (score 2):

Правильней будет передавать значение переменной как указал   **avengerweb** (приношу извинение за неточность)

```
data:{ article_title:article_title }
```

И проверьте что у вас заходит в ajax , через тот же  **alert** или консоль, далее проверьте что у ваз попадает в **php** код, и корректно ли там все отрабатывается

Comment: Решил убрать код php. Разместил тут http://jsfiddle.net/T4tcr/3/ и срабатывает событие ошибки. Это нормально (так как не указан url и данные никакие не передаются)? Или нет?

Comment: Здесь вроде все нормально. Пробуйте проанализировать что у вас попадает в РНР-код, и как это дел там обыгрывается.

Comment: А почему тогда срабатывает ошибка alert? Ведь в принципе должна работать ветка успешного добавления товара мне кажется...

Comment: Странно, у меня ошибка alert не генериться... 
Т.е. при клике на кнопку никакой реакции...
Но если я добавляю alert с выводом нужной нам переменной то отрабатывается только он.

Comment: Похоже условие if(response == "OK") {...}else {...} вообще не работает. Без условия alert работает...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DR9g9rLR